Why is there no more common header packages for newer kernels?
I mean the linux-header-<linux version number> package that has no flavor. IIRC earlier such a package was dependence of each linux-header-<linux version number>-<flavor>, but this does not seem to be the case anymore except for generic flavor. Instead, there seems to be linux-<flavor>-headers-<linux version number> that seems to be dependence for other flavors.

It's a virtual package provided by the more specific linux-headers-<flavour> packages. What's the problem you're having?

@muru no, they are not virtual packages, but provide common files needed by linux-headers of different flavors. For example, dpkg-query -L linux-headers-5.15.0-119 lists 18720 files. I am author of linux-purge and naming and dependency changes of kernel related packages affects to it.

I didn't say linux-headers-<whatever> is a virtual package. I said linux-headers (which is what you're asking about) is virtual.

@muru linux-headers is not a package (at least in 22.04). I meant versioned package such as linux-headers-5.15.0-119 that does not have a flavor such as -generic in its name. Though in 22.04 even that seems to be specific to generic flavor, as the only reserve dependence is linux-headers-5.15.0-119-generic. Wheras linux-headers-5.15.0-119-lowlatency depends on linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-119.

It's a virtual package, even in 22.04. Let me repeat for the fourth time since you seem to have missed it in the first two comments: VIRTUAL. But you still haven't explained what the problem is, other than saying you're writing some script.

@muru Oh, I see. Oddly e.g. linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic provides linux-headers-3.0 besides linux-headers even the real package has higher version. You referred to Debian documentation, but as for Debian linux, though linux-headers is not in the AUTHORITATIVE LIST OF VIRTUAL PACKAGE NAMES. Anyway, I am not interested in virtual packages. I am interested in kernel related real packages, their naming conventions and mutual dependencies.

I linked to the Debian docs, because the definition comes from there, but naturally Ubuntu's packages won't be in Debian's list. Even going back to Ubuntu 14.04, linux-headers-X.Y.Z-W had only linux-headers-X.Y.Z-W-generic as an rdepends (just checked  linux-headers-3.13.0-24 in a Docker container).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
